# How to push key and value into array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Tried to push new key and value but not working.Here given my code. Do not use {'id5':5} Because i am not trying to push object 1. Trying inside object 0

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1guupk

```js
items = [{
  'id1': 1,
  'id2': 2,
  'id3': 3,
  'id4': 4
}];
items.push('id5': 5);
console.log(items);
```

Output should be:

```
console.log(items);

     0: Object
     id1: 1
     id2: 2
     id3: 3
     id4: 4
     id5: 5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var items = [{
    'id1': 1,
    'id2': 2,
    'id3': 3,
    'id4': 4
}];

// items[0] is an object
items[0].id5= 5;
console.log(items)
```

Comment: maybe you could add value to your answer by explaining why his way can't work

Comment: @jonatjano  maybe you could read my answer and see the comment `items[0] is an object`

Comment: @8HoLoN I've seen it, but from the question, it's obvious OP need to be informed of the difference between arrays and object

Comment: How to convert array to object  like ver test=[{'id;:1}]  to test={'id;:1}   ???\

Comment: Just i am asking you

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use `.push()` method on an object, that doesn't work.
To get your result you have to add a property to an object.

For more info visit documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

```js
items = [{
   'id1': 1, 
   'id2': 2, 
   'id3': 3, 
   'id4': 4
   }];
items[0]['id5'] =  5;
console.log(items);
```

Comment: maybe you could add value to your answer by explaining why his way can't work

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this task by Destructuring the object

```js
var items = [{
  'id1': 1,
  'id2': 2,
  'id3': 3,
  'id4': 4
}];

items = [{
  ...items[0],
  'id5': 5
}]

console.log(items)
```

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: That did not work like you expected. Please always post a snippet

Comment: You mean `items = [{ ...items[0], 'id5': 5 }]`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for you because:

1- items is an array of objects when you push something to the array you add another value to the array example :

```
items.push("hello")
```

it results :

```
items = [{
  'id1': 1,
  'id2': 2,
  'id3': 3,
  'id4': 4
},
"hello"
];
```

2- your object is just the first element of the array (items[0])

```
items[0] == {
    'id1': 1,
    'id2': 2,
    'id3': 3,
    'id4': 4
}
```

3- you can access properties or add a new property to this object by a key this way:

```
items[0][key] = value; //key as a string
```

or

```
items[0].key = value;
```

it will override the value if the key already existe or add a new one otherwise.